# Upgrading to pip version 9.0.1

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am getting the following error message when installing some libraries on PyCharm:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hachoir-metadata\
>   You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade
>   pip' command.

Path to pip3.5.exe:

```
C:\Users\user.name>AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pip3.5.exe
```

I have run the following from cmd:

```
C:\Users\user.name>AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pip3.5.exe install upgrade pip
```

Which gives me the following:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for upgrade You are using
>   pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available. You should
>   consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'
>   command.

I then tried both:

```
C:\Users\user.name>AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pip.exe pip install upgrade pip
```

and:

```
C:\Users\user.name>AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pip.exe python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

From pip.exe (rather than pip3.5exe as they didn't work on that) which resulted in:

> ERROR: unknown command

I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong here, but not quite sure what?

Tried the following:
C:\Users\user.name>\AppData\Local\Programs-m pip install --upgrade pip

```
C:\Users\user.name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pip.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
C:\Users\user.name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: are you sure about the python path, is it install here ? `C:\Users\user.name>AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32`

Comment: Not sure if it also happens with Windows, but in Ubuntu pip version has been patched to 8.1.2 to prevent self-upgrades, so even if version 9 exist it will not upgrade.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674368/pip-refuses-to-upgrade

Comment: @Surajano, yes this is where it is installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` as the command, not as an argument to `pip.exe`. This will call `python.exe` with `-m pip install --upgrade pip` as arguments.

Also make sure you are running this from a command prompt with admin rights.

Comment: Thinks for this, I did try it but still no luck - see update for what I tried. Would you mind specifying the full path of what you think it would be? Sorry to be a pain, but this would help me see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Maverick, if python.exe isn't in `PATH`, then you could use `py -3.5-32 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Remember the two dashes in front of "upgrade"; a couple of your attempts in the question forgot this. If `py.exe` also isn't found, then use the absolute path to your interpreter: `"%LocalAppdata%\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Note what the `-m` option is doing; it imports and runs `pip` as the `__main__` module.  You can't use the pip.exe script wrapper for this because upgrading has to replace it.

Comment: Christian, the OP doesn't need admin rights in this case. That's the main selling point for defaulting to a per-user install.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @eryksun - the accepted answer belongs to you.